# I want row number in view Or variable in View

Tags: mysql, view, row-number

I know it is not possible directly.
But I want to achieve this by any indirect method if possible.

Actually I wanted to add below query to view which throws error , Sub query not allowed in view.

```
select T1.Code,
       T1.month,
       T1.value,
       IfNull(T2.Value,0)+IfNull(T3.value,0) as value_begin

  from (select *,@rownum := @rownum + 1 as rownum
          from Table1 
          Join (SELECT @rownum := 0) r) T1
  left join (select *,@rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 as rownum
               from Table1 
               Join (SELECT @rownum1 := 0) r) T2
    on T1.code = T2.code
   and T1.rownum = T2.rownum + 1
  left join (select *,@rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 as rownum
               from Table1 
               Join (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r) T3
    on T1.code = T3.code
   and T1.rownum = T3.rownum + 2
 Order by T1.Code,T1.rownum
```

So, I thought I will make Sub query as separate view but that again throws error that variables not allowed in view. Please Help to overcome this situation.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could try the method of triangle join + count for assigning row numbers. It will likely not perform well on large datasets, but instead you should be able to implement everything with a couple of views (if you think there's no other way to do what you want to do than with a view). The idea is as follows:

1. The dataset is joined to itself on the condition of `master.key >= secondary.key`, where `master` is the instance where detail data will actually be pulled from, and `secondary` is the other instance of the same table used to provide the row numbers.
2. Based on that condition, the first<sup>*</sup> `master` row would be joined with one `secondary` row, the second one with two, the third one with three and so on.
3. At this point, you can group the result set by the master `key` column(s) as well as the columns that you need in the output (although [in MySQL it would be enough to group by the master key only](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html)). Count the rows in every group will give you corresponding row numbers.

So, if there was a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (
  ID int,
  Value int
);
```

the query to assign row numbers to the table could look like this:

```
SELECT m.ID, m.Value, COUNT(*) AS rownum
FROM SomeTable AS m
INNER JOIN SomeTable AS s ON m.ID >= s.ID
GROUP BY m.ID, m.Value
;
```

Since you appear to want to self-join the ranked rowset (and twice too), that would require using the above query as a derived table, and since you also want the entire thing to be a view (which doesn't allow subqueries in the FROM clause), you would probably need to define the ranking query as a separate view:

```
CREATE RankingView AS
SELECT m.ID, m.Value, COUNT(*) AS rownum
FROM SomeTable AS m
INNER JOIN SomeTable AS s ON m.ID >= s.ID
GROUP BY m.ID, m.Value
;
```

and subsequently refer to that view in the main query:

```
CREATE SomeOtherView AS
SELECT ...
FROM RankingView AS t1
LEFT JOIN RankingView AS t2 ON ...
...
```

[This SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05234/1) shows the method and its usage.

One note with regard to your particular situation. Your table probably needs row numbers to be assigned *in partitions*, i.e. every distinct `Code` row group needs its own row number set. That means that your ranking view should specify the joining condition as something like this:

```
ON m.Code = s.Code AND m.Month >= s.Month
```

Please note that months in this case are assumed to be unique per `Code`. If that is not the case, you may first need to create a view that groups the original dataset by `Code, Month` and rank that view instead of the original dataset.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> According to the order of `key`.</sub>

Comment: wow i'm so thoroughly frustrated with this right now!  if i could just use postgres, i would be fine.  i have no idea why mysql doesn't have a ROW_NUMBER function yet.

Comment: my problem is that i'm using view-backed models in Ruby on Rails, so i have some real constraints with what i can do.  i have 13,000 rows in this table, so the triangular join is not an option for me.  and because i'm using a view, neither are the variables.  the only way i've been able to solve this so far is to use multiple joins, as above.  however, the customer now wants 6 records, instead of just 3.  so i really have no idea what i'm going to do.... SMH

Comment: Why can you not switch to a different product? The project already too big?